# OpenCV Classify currencies using Hue channel

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to develop an android application for paper currency identification by capturing images, I have tried template matching method but it is a scale variance, and it doesn't give an accurate match, I am thinking to use calculate Histogram method, will I get a better results?

Also, how can I classify currencies of different colors based on Hue channel ??

Comment: What kind of coins? Can you show an example picture? Depending on the conditions, some methods can be considered or discarded.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a case where a recognition based on SIFT or SURF features can give you good results.

Extract SURF features from those images and build a `FlannBasedMatcher` (or other matcher). Then, extract SURF features from the input image, use the matcher to compute distances between the input features and those in your training images. Select corresponding features with lower descriptor distance and check if you have enough of them. If your input image has a lot of background, to check if your guess is correct, you can also compute a homography with those correspondences.

There is an example in the OpenCV doc to do something very similar to this.

Comment: thanks and sorry for disturbing,but I know that surf and sift are non free package, Do you know if it possible to identify the currencies with its color a method or  a link that can help??

Comment: I think ORB features are patent-free. A histogram of hue values can be a good approach as well, since the notes seem to be quite different regarding their color. Then, you can compute the similarity/dissimilarity of the histograms with some distance as the L2, Bhattacharyya or KL divergence.